# Is there a statistical test to test whether a time series behaves like a Brownian motion?

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables, brownian-motion

[image: simulated data]

The observed data that I am dealing with is pictured above. It is generated by some mathematical algorithm (simulations) described in section 4.1.(c) in my article, [here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/fascinating-new-results-in-the-theory-of-randomness) (data available in spreadsheet in my article.) I could not find any statistical test in the literature, except [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08553) by Grzegorz Sikora (not yet published).

Comment: I asked the question on Quora, and got an interesting answer. Here is the [link](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-statistical-test-to-test-whether-a-time-series-behaves-like-a-Brownian-motion) to the answer.